# uploading attachment - restricting file size - IE cannot display the webpage

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

i am trying to test to see if i get an error if i upload more than 3mb file size but instead i get the IE error (see below)

here is the code i have. - what i want is if the user try to upload more than 3mb file size display an error.

```
 if (fUpload.HasFile)
 {
   // Get the size in bytes of the file to upload.            
   int fileSize = fUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
  // Allow only files less than 3145728 bytes (approximately 3 MB) to be uploaded.
  if (fileSize > 3145728) //if (fUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 3072) 
  {
     ..............
     .............
  }
  else
  {
    // Notify the user why their file was not uploaded.                
    this.lblStatus.Text = "Your file was not uploaded because it exceeds the 3 MB size limit.";
  }
}

<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="3145728" />


Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage
This problem can be caused by a variety of issues, including: 

•Internet connectivity has been lost.
•The website is temporarily unavailable.
•The Domain Name Server (DNS) is not reachable.
•The Domain Name Server (DNS) does not have a listing for the website's domain.
•There might be a typing error in the address.
•If this is an HTTPS (secure) address, click Tools, click Internet Options, click Advanced, and check to be sure the SSL and TLS protocols are enabled under the security section.
```

Comment: can you capsulate this in a try-catch block and try to debug this issue?

Comment: i have the break point in the begining of the event but it never goes there so its not even exeucting the code it just redirect to the IE error which i have posted above.

Comment: yes, it starts the upload with the postback and if the file is greater than maxRequestLength the error occurs before you could check the file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how i fix it:

By Default, you should be able to upload a file upto 4MB and MaxRequestLength is in Kilo Bytes. So, Default value is 4096KB. If you try to upload the file with size over 4MB, you will get an error. So, Increase that to some 25Mb or a large number. Then you should be able to track file size in your code.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this on server side. This means the file already has been started to upload to the server. I couldn't find a solution too and I don't know if there is one for this issue.

Comment: how it will start to upload without executing the code? i have breakpoint but it never break there

Comment: It works for small file, but for big size file its not even executing the code it just display ie error:......strange